# sites.google - anyway to harvest the data

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sites

We have a shiny new Google Site that tracks the position of cyclists over a 1200km event.

The issue is that the content in the list needs to go into a mySQL database and I wondered if anyone had managed to loop through or transfer the content into a csv or similar from the list with test rider. I can see that working through json might be able to do this but I am concerned that this approach could fail.

I've worked a little in Google scripts for spreadsheets but not entirely sure where to start or even where to look. The site is at...

https://sites.google.com/site/audaxsm2013progress/sydney-canberra-day-1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with sitesApp in apps script and come back if your siteApp code is not working..

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/sites/sites-app

Comment: Whilst I can get a lot of the surrounding information, I don't think, at this point in time, I can get the individual cells from the list although I've run out of time. I am adding the accepted solution on the grounds that it gave me the right direction to follow. Thanks @zig_Mandel